# substitute a argument x into var string python

Tags: python

I have a function in python

```
def func(x):
   #  x is int
   for cell in list1:
      # gets each cell
      print cell
```

how to use eval to calculate new string?

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: You start by recognizing that a list of strings is a terrible way to encode a list of functions. `list1` should be `[lambda x: x+3, lambda x: x/3, lambda x: x*3]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to substitute. You want to evaluate the expression. I would suggest you try something like this:

```
variables = { x: 900 }
cell = 'x+3'
result = eval(cell, locals=variables)
```

This will evaluate the `cell` expression *using python syntax*. As long as your cell formulas are simple enough, that will probably be okay. If you start trying to do Excel spreadsheet formulas, you will need to do a lot more work.

Comment: Thank you for the response.. but where should I write the variables ={} and cell = {} ?

Comment: That depends on you. The cell='' stuff can be replaced by `for cell in cells:` or whatever code you need to run to evaluate all the cells. The `variables={}` can either be an outer thing (like, this applies to all cells) or a specific thing for each cell. It will be based on the requirements of your app.